# js response with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, associations

i'm doing a crossdomain ajax call to get some data out of my rails app. For that i've used an awesome method i found which works like a charm. However Rails doesn't render the associations affiliated along with it. Because i do want that information i tried changing my format.js but failed horribly at formatting correct output.

This is what i have now in my trips show method(Which works perfectly):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.js { render_json @trip.to_json }  
end
```

But i want to render @trip.triplocations aswell. But i don't know how. Is anyone out there who knows this?

Just in case, here's the awesome method i found:

```
def render_json(json, options={})
  callback, variable = params[:callback], params[:variable]
  response = begin
    if callback && variable
      "var #{variable} = #{json};\n#{callback}(#{variable});"
    elsif variable
      "var #{variable} = #{json};"
    elsif callback
      "#{callback}(#{json});"
    else
      json
    end
  end
  render({:content_type => :js, :text => response}.merge(options))
end
```

(Props go to: http://www.sitepoint.com/json-p-output-with-rails/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(BTW: Do you really need this render_json method? )

```
format.js {render :json=> @trip.as_json(:include => :triplocations)}
```

The :include method will include associations. works for higher levels too. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: Apparantly for crossdomain access(jsonp) you do. Read the link given and thanks for the answer!